# Vim Replace On Each Line With Different String

Tags: vim

I've got a document from a client which has a GIANT table in it which looks something like this:

```
<table id="someid">
<tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td class="product1">Product 1</td>
    <td class="product2">Product 2</td>
    <td class="product3">Product 3</td>
    <td class="product4">Product 4</td>
    <td class="product5">Product 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Boiling Point</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>91</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>41</td>
</tr>
[ 45 more rows here]
</table>
```

Only there are actually 15 products, and instead of "product1" and "product2" they have the actual name of the products as their preexisting classes.

The client has asked me to add classes to each of the appropriate td elements so that they are matched up with their product like class="product1" added to each 2nd td for every row.

Everything is static... I'm wondering if there's a quick way to do this in vim? Is it possible to tell vim to add a string to a certain position on every 18th line? Or am I stuck manually adding all the classes?

Comment: Can you provide a before/after, to illustrate what you want to do, the current explanation is not that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the relation between your class name and the line number can be described as an expression, you can use `:[range]substitute` and `s/\=` to replace lines with any expression. For example,

```
1,10s/<td/\=submatch(0) . ' class="product' . (line('.') % 5 - 1) . '"'
```

will change

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tr>
  <td class="product1"></td>
  <td class="product2"></td>
  <td class="product3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="product1"></td>
  <td class="product2"></td>
  <td class="product3"></td>
</tr>
```

You can adapt those arguments in the above command to suit your needs.

---

For complex replacement, you can define a helper function in a temporary vim file such as `foo.vim`

```
function! GetClassName()
  let order = line('.') % 5

  if order == 1
    return 'a'
  endif

  if order == 2
    return 'b'
  endif
endfunction
```

then source it by `:source %`.

Next, you can switch to your file and use it as follows

```
1,10s/^\s\+<td/\=submatch(0) . ' class="' . GetClassName() . '"'
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd do if the class names actually were "product1", "product2", etc... but the class names are like "widget", "something-else", "another-product". 

What I need is something like 
"If the line number (inside of this range) mod 18 = 5, add this arbitrary class name. If the line number mod 18 = 6, add this other arbitrary class name." etc. 

And I could do that as 15 separate commands, but I don't know how to do the "if the line number mod some other number = target" part.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope it helps.